# Excel vlookup for 2 different cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, statistics, vlookup

so i am doing a statistic's project and i need to combine the tables with one another since the tables do not have the same countries i need to use vlookup in excel to combine it

the main problem is: in the table there are countries and years which need to be in 2 columns but when using vlookup it only returns the 1st value that it finds with the country's name so all the years belgium has the same internet rate returned when in fact it doesn't

so this is the function that i used(in order to get the internet rates for each country): =VLOOKUP($A16,Internet_Zugangsdichte!$A$2:$C$469,3,FALSE)

[this is the table where i had to put the value with the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU2YK.png)

[this is the table that i have to look for the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9jfn.png)

Comment: [This may be useful](https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/vlookup-display-multiple-matches-or-results/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not switch to using `sumifs(internet rate, country column, country, year column, year`?
If you are set on using vlookups (or the superior xlookup) then create a lookup column in column d in your second screenshot using `=A2&B2` and in your first table use `=xlookup(A2&B2,$D:$D, $C:$C`